# COMBO BOX dynamic value read/update using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var commonKey=primaryKey+"_"+code+"_"+FromDate;
var code= $("input[type='text'][name$='Code"+commonKey+"']").val();
```

The screen contains more 4 rows,which will take updated values for text type.

But I'm unable to execute it for the `COMBOX` type.

```
var Type = document.getElementById("cmb&D|Grid5_"+primaryKey+"").value;
```

which only gives first value only always.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `document.getElementById` only returns one value because ids *should* be unique

Comment: var code= $("input[type='cmb'][name$='Code"+commonKey+"']").val(); it is not working for combo box type...any luck